# How does a hybrid argument work relating to PRG's?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, distinguisher

How does a hybrid argument work relating to PRG's?
I am working on a homework assignment where the problems say to use a hybrid argument to prove/disprove that something is a secure PRG, and I can't find an explanation of this idea anywhere online or in the notes which makes sense to me.

I think the idea is to have a sequence of distributions where each pair of successive distributions is indistinguishable, but I can't imagine how to construct such a sequence. And if I did have such a sequence, well I understand how to use a hybrid argument to show that something *is* a PRG from there, but not how to show that something isn't a PRG.

What I mean is that one of the problems says something like we'll construct a PRG $G$ from other PRG's $G_1, G_2,$ and $G_3$. Then use a hybrid argument to prove that $G$ is a PRG, by showing that a PPT which breaks $G$ can be used to construct a PPT that breaks $G_1,$ or $G_2$ or $G_3$. To be honest I have no clue how to do that, and I've been trying to figure it out for hours.

I think that the construction of $G$ is relevant, so I'll tell you it is defined like this: $G(s)$ is computed by taking $G_1(s) = s_2||s_3$, and then returning $G_2(s_2)||G_3(s_3)$. This is with $s, s_2$ and $s_3$ of length $n$, and $G_2(s_2)$ and $G_3(s_3)$ of length $3_n$. Oh and I'm using $||$ as string concatenation, I'm not sure how standard that is.

Any suggestions, or explanations of these concepts would be greatly appreciated! And let me know if this is the wrong place to post this, I wasn't sure.